# i am confused in giving app access in google play console while releasing the app

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-play-console

Google play console asking me for credentials if my app have authentications. Actually my app have google authentication should i give my gmail and password in it.

Comment: Have you considered setting up a test account? That way you can share the credentials and they can test all aspects of your app without exposing any personal information.

Comment: no. Is test account was mandatory ?

Comment: I don't think it's mandatory, but that's how I would set it up. Just to make sure that no sensitive information somehow ends up where it shouldn't.